# Sendgrid V3 NodeJS into separate fundtion file

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I have a NodeJS Express app that when a user sends a POST request to a route it then should fetch some info from the DB and then insert this into the call to SendGrid v3 API.

The data from the DB is to do with the route, which I have working fine as the route is /api/:id which is the MongoDB id of a document.

I have the SendGrid code working in the route but I wanted to put this in a separate file to try to keep my routes files cleaner and also for DRY purposes as I will want to use the Mailer class for other parts of the application.

I am using this link as the base for my code: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sendgrid-v3-nodejs-transactional-email-cloud-function/ but this is just in the route whereas I want it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Put your mail functions in a specific route and call the mail route in your /api/:id route :

```
post("/api/:id", function(req, res, next){

   // do db things
   // send post request to /mail/myObject/:id
   // do others things

   // return result

});


post("/mail/myObject/:id", function(req, res, next){

   // get my document from db
   // connect to sendgrid

   // return result

});
```